# Is there a way to free swap?

Tags: memory, swap, vmware-player

After using vmware player with some virtual machine, it seems like my swap stays quite occupied and it doesn't changes unless i reboot it.

However, regularly swap is not used much by other applications.

Configuration is bit unusual:

Swap is about 1Gb
RAM is: 16Gb

Is there a way to free that swap after using vmware player?
Should i worry about that at all?

Comment: swapoff interrupted with C-c?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should not worry about it at all. The OS will put inactive memory pages into swap, and let them sit there if it's not being used.

Comment: Then, there is a bug in System Monitor applet :D